# shopwaredata.shipping_method_price_new_price_update already exists

Tags: shopware

i try to install shopware 6 but got everytime the same error:

Setup:

AMD Hexa-Core 6 Cores x 2.8 GHz(3.3 GHz Turbo Core), 16 GB Ram

PHP 7.4.15

-Max values that i try-

Memory limit 3GB

max_execution_time 30000

max_input_time 60000

post_max_size 1024M

upload_max_filesize 1024M

opcache.enable on

allow_url_fopen on

--Database--

Maria DB

10.3.27-MariaDB-1:10.3.27+maria~bionic

---

Error

Received an error message.
URL: importDatabase
Message:

```
{"valid":false,"errorMsg":"An exception occurred while executing 'CREATE TRIGGER shipping_method_price_new_price_update BEFORE UPDATE ON shipping_method_price\n            FOR EACH ROW\n            BEGIN\n                IF @TRIGGER_DISABLED IS NULL OR @TRIGGER_DISABLED = 0 THEN\n                IF (NEW.price != OLD.price OR (NEW.price IS NOT NULL AND OLD.price IS NULL))\n                        OR (NEW.currency_id != OLD.currency_id OR (NEW.currency_id IS NOT NULL AND OLD.currency_id IS NULL))\n                        AND (NEW.currency_price = OLD.currency_price OR (NEW.currency_price IS NULL AND OLD.currency_price IS NULL)) THEN\n                    SET NEW.currency_price = JSON_OBJECT(\n                        CONCAT(\"c\", LOWER(HEX(NEW.currency_id))),\n                        JSON_OBJECT(\n                            \"net\", NEW.price,\n                            \"gross\", NEW.price,\n                            \"linked\", false,\n                            \"currencyId\", LOWER(HEX(NEW.currency_id))\n                        )\n                    );\n                ELSEIF (NEW.price = OLD.price OR NEW.price IS NULL)\n                        AND (NEW.currency_id = OLD.currency_id OR NEW.currency_id IS NULL)\n                        AND (NEW.currency_price != OLD.currency_price OR (OLD.currency_price IS NULL AND NEW.currency_price IS NOT NULL)) THEN\n                    SET NEW.price = JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(\n                        NEW.currency_price,\n                        CONCAT(\"$.\", JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_KEYS(NEW.currency_price), \"$[0]\")), \".gross\")\n                    )) + 0.0;\n\n                    SET NEW.currency_id = UNHEX(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(\n                        NEW.currency_price,\n                        CONCAT(\"$.\", JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_KEYS(NEW.currency_price), \"$[0]\")), \".currencyId\")\n                    )));\n                END IF;\n                END IF;\n            END;':\n\nSQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1359 Trigger 'shopwaredata.shipping_method_price_new_price_update' already exists"}
```

Please try to fix this error and restart the update.

Answer (score 0):

> General error: 1359 Trigger 'shopwaredata.shipping_method_price_new_price_update' already exists"}

The error says that the trigger is already existing. Please clean up your database and try to re-run the installation.

Comment: I do that a serval times. I also try to use a fresh crated database 2 times too. Nothing work :/